# Rounded corners in views using XML

Tags: xml, android-layout, rounded-corners

I am trying to create views with rounded corners but my XML has these errors: `android:shape`, `android:color`, and `android:radius` on the code. I would really appreciate a solution:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: can you add the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

These kind questions have a lot of answers already written. 
If you do a little more research you will easily find the answer.
But still, I am writing an answer. ignore if you find it repetitive.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
```

Create a new resource file with the above code and set it as a background to any views. you can expect the background to be like below screenshot.

```
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_rectangle_black"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sabarinathan, your feedback helped.